# Align two nodes of different tikzpicture at the center of the page

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem with the alignment of two tikzpicture environments.

```
\documentclass[14pt,spanish]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{subscript}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{inicio} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=yellow]
\tikzstyle{nodo} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]  
        \node (fosforo) [inicio] {Fósforo};

        \node (ortofosfato) [nodo, below of=fosforo] {Ortofosfato (\ce{P-PO_4^{3-}})}; \draw [arrow] (fosforo) -- node [anchor=west] {medido como} (ortofosfato);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        \node (nitrogeno) [inicio] {Nitrógeno};

        \node (nitrato) [nodo, below of=nitrogeno, xshift=-2.5cm] {Nitrato (\ce{N-NO_3^{-}})}; \draw [arrow] (nitrogeno) -- node [anchor=east,xshift=-0.5cm] {medido como} (nitrato);
        \node (amonio) [nodo, below of=nitrogeno, xshift=2.5cm] {Amonio (\ce{N-NH_4^+})}; \draw [arrow] (nitrogeno) -- node [anchor=west,xshift=0.5cm] {medido como} (amonio);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I want that the nodes "fosforo" and "nitrogeno" get aligned horizontally in the center of the page. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Could you please provide a Minimum (non-)Working Example so that those who want to help can generate your problem. As it stands, this does not compile.

Comment: @Jesse Should I put all the code generated by Lyx?

Comment: Not all, just make it to minimal that shows your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top node is centered on `(0,0)`, so you can use `trim left` and `trim right` to make the picture symmetric about this axis.  As there is nothing else on the same line, it is enough to make the picture of zero width.  Thus you can add

```
trim left=0pt,trim right=0pt
```

as the options to these pictures.  In the following I have defined a style `centerzero` for this:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[14pt,spanish]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{subscript}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{inicio} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm,
  minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=yellow] 
\tikzstyle{nodo} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm,
  minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black] 
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{centerzero} = [trim left=0pt,trim right=0pt]

\usepackage{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,centerzero]  
        \node (fosforo) [inicio] {Fósforo};

        \node (ortofosfato) [nodo, below of=fosforo] {Ortofosfato
          (\ce{P-PO_4^{3-}})}; 
        \draw [arrow] (fosforo) -- node [anchor=west] {medido como}
          (ortofosfato); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,centerzero]
        \node (nitrogeno) [inicio] {Nitrógeno};

        \node (nitrato) [nodo, below of=nitrogeno, xshift=-2.5cm]
          {Nitrato (\ce{N-NO_3^{-}})}; 
        \draw [arrow] (nitrogeno) -- node [anchor=east,xshift=-0.5cm]
          {medido como} (nitrato); 
        \node (amonio) [nodo, below of=nitrogeno, xshift=2.5cm]
          {Amonio (\ce{N-NH_4^+})}; 
        \draw [arrow] (nitrogeno) -- node [anchor=west,xshift=0.5cm]
          {medido como} (amonio); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to make sure this figures have a fixed non-zero width, you could put

```
trim left=-8cm,trim right=8cm
```

making the `tikzpicture` 16cm wide with `(0,0)` in the middle horizontally.

Incidentally you have made these `figure`s with placement options `h!` and no caption.  If you just want a picture at the current position (without caption) then the `center` environment is much more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I put the two tikzpictures inside one figure environment. That puts them side by side. I added vertical spaces before and after the figure to have it centered vertically.

```
\documentclass[14pt,spanish]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{subscript}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{inicio} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=yellow]
\tikzstyle{nodo} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]  
        \node (fosforo) [inicio] {Fósforo};

        \node (ortofosfato) [nodo, below of=fosforo] {Ortofosfato (\ce{P-PO_4^{3-}})}; \draw [arrow] (fosforo) -- node [anchor=west] {medido como} (ortofosfato);
    \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}%
%\begin{figure}[h!]
%    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        \node (nitrogeno) [inicio] {Nitrógeno};

        \node (nitrato) [nodo, below of=nitrogeno, xshift=-2.5cm] {Nitrato (\ce{N-NO_3^{-}})}; \draw [arrow] (nitrogeno) -- node [anchor=east,xshift=-0.5cm] {medido como} (nitrato);
        \node (amonio) [nodo, below of=nitrogeno, xshift=2.5cm] {Amonio (\ce{N-NH_4^+})}; \draw [arrow] (nitrogeno) -- node [anchor=west,xshift=0.5cm] {medido como} (amonio);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\vfill

\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution is good for this two tikzpicture, but I have other tikzpicture in my document in other pages. I want that all the principal nodes are aligned in the center of the page.